# Is there a way to deal with nested data with sparklyr?

Tags: r, tidyr, sparklyr

In the following example I've loaded a parquet file that contains a nested record of map objects in the `meta` field. `sparklyr` seems to do a nice job of dealing with these. However `tidyr::unnest` does not translate to SQL (or HQL - understandably - like `LATERAL VIEW explode()`) and is thus not usable. Is there a way to unnest data some other way?

```
tfl <- head(tf)
tfl
Source:   query [?? x 10]
Database: spark connection master=yarn-client app=sparklyr local=FALSE

                            trkKey             meta     sources startTime
                             <chr>           <list>      <list>    <list>
1 3juPe-k0yiMcANNMa_YiAJfJyU7WCQ3Q <S3: spark_jobj> <list [24]> <dbl [1]>
2 3juPe-k0yiAJX3ocJj1fVqru-e0syjvQ <S3: spark_jobj>  <list [1]> <dbl [1]>
3 3juPe-k0yisY7UY_ufUPUo5mE1xGfmNw <S3: spark_jobj>  <list [7]> <dbl [1]>
4 3juPe-k0yikXT5FhqNj87IwBw1Oy-6cw <S3: spark_jobj> <list [24]> <dbl [1]>
5 3juPe-k0yi4MMU63FEWYTNKxvDpYwsRw <S3: spark_jobj>  <list [7]> <dbl [1]>
6 3juPe-k0yiFBz2uPbOQqKibCFwn7Fmlw <S3: spark_jobj> <list [19]> <dbl [1]>
# ... with 6 more variables: endTime <list>, durationInMinutes <dbl>,
#   numPoints <int>, maxSpeed <dbl>, maxAltitude <dbl>, primaryKey <chr>
```

There is also an issue when the data is collected. E.g.,

```
tfl <- head(tf) %>% collect()
tfl
# A tibble: 6 × 10
                            trkKey             meta     sources startTime
                             <chr>           <list>      <list>    <list>
1 3juPe-k0yiMcANNMa_YiAJfJyU7WCQ3Q <S3: spark_jobj> <list [24]> <dbl [1]>
2 3juPe-k0yiAJX3ocJj1fVqru-e0syjvQ <S3: spark_jobj>  <list [1]> <dbl [1]>
3 3juPe-k0yisY7UY_ufUPUo5mE1xGfmNw <S3: spark_jobj>  <list [7]> <dbl [1]>
4 3juPe-k0yikXT5FhqNj87IwBw1Oy-6cw <S3: spark_jobj> <list [24]> <dbl [1]>
5 3juPe-k0yi4MMU63FEWYTNKxvDpYwsRw <S3: spark_jobj>  <list [7]> <dbl [1]>
6 3juPe-k0yiFBz2uPbOQqKibCFwn7Fmlw <S3: spark_jobj> <list [19]> <dbl [1]>
# ... with 6 more variables: endTime <list>, durationInMinutes <dbl>,
#   numPoints <int>, maxSpeed <dbl>, maxAltitude <dbl>, primaryKey <chr>

tfl %>% unnest(meta)
Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [meta]
```

In the above, the `meta` file still contains `spark_jobj` elements instead of lists, data.frames, or even JSON strings (which is how Hive would return such data). This creates a situation where `tidyr` doesn't even work on the collected data.

Is there a way to get `sparklyr` to work more nicely with `tidyr` that I am missing? If not, is this planned for future `sparklyr` development?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally have my answer to this. See https://mitre.github.io/sparklyr.nested/ (source: https://github.com/mitre/sparklyr.nested)

```
tf %>% 
  sdf_unnest(meta)
```

This will behave for Spark data frames similarly to how `tidyr::unnest` behaves for local data frames. Nested select and explode operations are also implemented.

Update:

as @cem-bilge notes `explode` can be used inside `mutate`. This is effective in situations where the array is simple (character or numeric) but less great in other situations.

```
iris2 <- copy_to(sc, iris, name="iris")
iris_nst <- iris2 %>%
  sdf_nest(Sepal_Length, Sepal_Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width, .key="data") %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarize(data=collect_list(data))
```

Then

```
iris_nst %>% mutate(data = explode(data)) %>% sdf_schema_viewer()
```

produces

[image]

with the fields still nested (though exploded) whereas `sdf_unnest` yields

```
iris_nst %>% sdf_unnest(data) %>% sdf_schema_viewer()
```

[image]

Comment: I find it surprising, that this important functionality is not part of the sparklyr-package. I wonder why.

Comment: Would `sdf_separate_column` be n alternative solution to the problem of nested tables? https://github.com/rstudio/sparklyr/issues/690

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly a proper solution, however one work around is to use Hive to generate a table or view (e.g., `create view db_name.table_name as select ...`). that handles the explode operation. This serves up flat data for `sparklyr` to work on. Where `sc` is a spark connection via `sparklyr` one can use `DBI::dbGetQuery(sc, "USE db_name")` assuming Hive is configured and the view will then show up when listing tables with `src_tbls(sc)`. Once you execute `dat <- tbl(sc, "table_name")` then it should be smoother sailing from there.

Since this is not a `sparklyr` solution (but more of a Hive solution) I'll not accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option that doesn't depend on Hive (at least as directly, `LATERAL VIEW explode()` is a hive thing).

```
tf %>% 
  sdf_mutate(ft_sql_transformer(
    b, paste0("SELECT trkKey, a.fld1 as fld1, a.fld2 as fld2",
              "FROM __THIS__ LATERAL VIEW explode(__THIS__.meta) x AS a")))
```

I'm not going to accept this answer either since I would still like to see something like:

```
tf %>%
  sdf_mutate(a=ft_explode(meta))
```

but that would require support for nested select statements. Perhaps something like the `tidyr::unnest` syntax would do the trick:

```
tf %>%
  sdf_mutate(a=ft_explode(meta)) %>%
  unnest(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `explode()` directly in a `mutate()` to expand arrays in sparklyr.

```
df %>%
  mutate(my_values = explode(my_array))
```

Note: sparklyr.nested is *not* required for this.

Comment: This works great if  `my_array` is a simple character/numeric array. Trouble if it is an array of structs though.